# bind fails with Invalid Argument error

Tags: c, sockets, binding

**This is the final code, with no compile error but i'm still getting the "invalid argument" error!!**
   ========================================================================

## include

```
using namespace std;
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/x25.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <linux/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>



int main(int argc,char **argv,char **envp) {

    int x25_socket;
    struct sockaddr_x25 x25_address = {0};

    char x25_host[] ="10.0.0.1";
    const char name[] = "my name";

    x25_address.sx25_family = AF_X25;

    x25_socket = socket(AF_X25, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0);
     if (x25_socket == -1)
              cout << "error in create socket" << endl;

     strncpy(x25_address.sx25_addr.x25_addr, x25_host, 16);


    int bindNumber = bind(x25_socket,(struct sockaddr *)&x25_address,sizeof(x25_address));
     if (bindNumber == -1)
     {
         perror("error in bind ---");
         cout << "error in bind" << endl;
     }

     cout << write(x25_socket, name, 2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, but you don't need to specify a trailing null in a string literal. The compiler gives you one free.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    struct sockaddr_x25 x25_address = {0};
    char x25_host[] = "10.0.0.1"
    const char name[] = "my name";

    int x25_socket = socket(AF_X25, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0);
    if(x25_socket == -1)
    {
        printf(" error in create socket");
    }

    x25address.safamily = AF_X25;
    strncpy(x25_address.sx25_addr.x25_addr, x25_host, 16);

    int bindNumber = bind(x25_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&x25_address, sizeof(x25_address));
    if (bindNumber == -1)
    {
        perror("error in bind ---");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: compilation error!! 41: error: request for member ‘x25_addr’ in ‘x25_address.sockaddr_x25::sx25_family’, which is of non-class type ‘sa_family_t’

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part. `sx25_family` should be `sx25_addr`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is C (as @Doorknob pointed (+1)), this has a couple of compilation errors. Please fix them. For example, you have a space between two parts of the same variable name. Thus, the following lines:

```
   int x25 socket;
   struct sockaddr x25 address;
   int x25 length;
   char x25 host[]
```

should be:

```
   int x25_socket;
   struct sockaddr_x25 x25_address;
   int x25_length;
   char x25_host[]
```

Other than that, I dont see any logical flaw in the bind() itself.

Comment: `sockaddr_in` is for `AF_INET` only.  For `AF_X25`, you have to use `sockaddr_x25` instead.  So presumably, in the OP's code, `struct sockaddr x25 address` likely meant to be `struct sockaddr_x25 address` and not `struct sockaddr x25_address`.

Comment: The "should be" section of your answer still says `sockaddr` where it needs to say `sockaddr_x25` instead. They are not the same struct. I fixed it for you.